# WideCharToMultiByte not converting Russian

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to convert Russian characters to a std string using the following code . However the function utf8_encode is returing junk . I have used the utf8_encode from one of the referenced question on stackoverflow

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::wstring ws(L"процессов");
    std::string str = utf8_encode(ws);

    return 0;
}


std::string utf8_encode(const std::wstring &wstr)
{
    int size_needed = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    std::string strTo( size_needed, 0 );
    WideCharToMultiByte                  (CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), &strTo[0], size_needed, NULL, NULL);
    return strTo;
}
```

Comment: Sorry to tell you this, but 日本語じゃないです。

Comment: "процессов" is russian word and utf8_encode works fine

Comment: Why had you decided, that it returns junk? Where do you see it? Maybe, you are trying to read the Russian text by something not supporting it? Than you'll surely see junk.

Comment: I chek the variable str  and it doesnt show the expected value

Comment: How had you checked it? Have you checked the UTF codes in its HEX representation?

Comment: Ok when I get the value of the converted string ...I create a file with the string name on the disk . When I browse for the file name I do not see "процессов" in the file name , but some junk characters

Comment: And are you sure that your operational system shows file names in UTF8? Surely, the file names are not WIDE string. You are lucky it didn't destroyed your file system.